# Using an R function output within another function

Tags: r

I am adapting an open-source code from GitHub (https://github.com/PeterDSteinberg/RSWMM) to calibrate EPA-SWMM. The code is written in two parts -- RSWMM.r contains the functions needed to look up/ replace SWMM values, read in the calibration files etc. runRSWMM.r is a wrapper containing the optimization code that calls in the relevant RSWMM functions. I need to edit the RSWMM code to read in a .txt file and have written the following code to do so.

```
getLIDtimeseriesFromTxt <- function(TxtFile, dateformat = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M"){
  #RW (05/12/17): This function added to read in the appropriate CSV file 
  #containing the LID outputs
  library(chron)
  LID_data <- read.table(TxtFile, skip=9)
  times <- LID_data[,1]
  startTime <- as.chron("6/8/2006 1:00", format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M", tz="GMT") #M/D/YY H:MM
  simData <<- {}
  simData$times <<- (times/24)+startTime
  simData$obs <<- LID_data[,9] #the ninth column is ponding depth
  return(simData)
}

getCalDataFromCSV<-function(CSVFile,dateFormat="%m/%d/%y %H:%M"){

   temp=read.csv(file=CSVFile, header = TRUE, sep = ",", quote="\"", dec=".", fill = TRUE, comment.char="",stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
   calData<<-{}
   #RW (05/12/17): This line of code edited to match the date format pulled in from the simulation file. 
   calData$times<<-as.chron(temp[,1], format=dateFormat,tz="GMT")
   calData$obs<<-temp[,2]
   return(calData)
}

interpCalDataToSWMMTimes<-function(){
  mergedData <- merge(simData, calData, by="times")
  return(mergedData)
  #first column of mergedData are times as chrons,
  #second column is simulated data
  #third column is observed data
}
```

When I run the full code from runRSWMM, I get the error the "simData" is not found, which implies that I cannot use merge. However, this doesn't appear to be a problem with the variable "calData", which I can see in my global environment in RStudio. What is the difference in the way the two variables are being output? How can I fix this error?

Comment: How are functions being called? As is, fcts are just being defined. I am sure if your replace (or switch order) of *simData*, the bugger will then complain about *calData*. It just failed on first one and program ended there.

Comment: Also, as a general R programming note, `<<-` should be avoided unless absolutely necessary (and it doesn't look necessary here, to me).

Comment: The function is being called in the runRSWMM wrapper script. It's being run as a part of an optimization code: out=optim(optimOpt$initial,objectiveFunction,
  gr = NULL, baseOutputName= optimOpt$baseOutputName,
     SWMMTemplateFile=optimOpt$SWMMTemplateFile,
     SWMMexe=optimOpt$SWMMexe,
       functionCallToEvalForASWMMTimeSeries= optimOpt$functionCallToEvalForASWMMTimeSeries,
     performanceStat=optimOpt$performanceStat,
      method = optimOpt$method,
      lower = optimOpt$lower, upper = optimOpt$upper,
      control = list(), hessian = FALSE)

Comment: optimOpt$functionCallToEvalForASWMMTimeSeries is defined as optimOpt$functionCallToEvalForASWMMTimeSeries='getLIDtimeseriesFromTxt()'

Comment: Also, I just checked what happened if I switched the order of calData and simData and I still get the same error.